# fillna by other dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem:

```
import pandas
df1=pandas.DataFrame([['2017-1-22',25,None],['2017-1-23','',''],['2017-1-24',24,15]],columns=['date','high_tem','low_tem'])
df2=pandas.DataFrame([['2017-1-22',22,18],['2017-1-23',23,''],['2017-1-24',20,10]],columns=['date','high_tem','low_tem'])
df3=pandas.DataFrame([['2017-1-22',25,16],['2017-1-23',24,18],['2017-1-24',22,11]],columns=['date','high_tem','low_tem'])
```

the df1,df2,df3 like this:

```
        date high_tem low_tem
0  2017-1-22       25    None
1  2017-1-23                 
2  2017-1-24       24      15
        date  high_tem low_tem
0  2017-1-22        22      18
1  2017-1-23        23        
2  2017-1-24        20      10
        date  high_tem  low_tem
0  2017-1-22        25       16
1  2017-1-23        24       18
2  2017-1-24        22       11
```

I try get the result like this:

```
         date  high_tem  low_tem
0  2017-1-22        22       18
1  2017-1-23        24       18
2  2017-1-24        24       15
```

the None is in df1 first rows(the index=0). So I use the df2 first row(which have the same date with df1 first rows) to replace it.

the Null string is in df1 second row(the index=1), the df2 second have null string.So I use the df3 second row to replce it.

the df1 thrid row doesn't contain None and Null string, I don't change this row.

Thanks

Comment: It would be worth specifying how you want to cycle through your DataFrames and a rule for filling NaN values from which DataFrame.

Comment: @oliversm, the order is df1 df2 df3. if df1 rows contain None or null string then check df2, and if df2 row contain None or null string then check df3. else None.

Comment: So you are only interested in the resulting `df1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through each dataframe and replace `None` and empty strings with `np.NaN`. Whenever there are presence of any `NaNs`, fill the complete row with it.

```
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    df.replace({None: np.NaN, "": np.NaN}, inplace=True)
    df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1), ['high_tem', 'low_tem']] = np.NaN
```

Following this, `df1`, `df2` and `df3` would be modified accordingly.

Use [`DF.combine_first()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) in `df1→df2→df3` order to fill the missing values.

```
df1.combine_first(df2).combine_first(df3)
```

[image]